# Prove all multiples of $U$ contain all the digits $0$ to $9$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have to prove that the number $U = 5263157894736842101$ is a "constant number" (that is, every positive multiple of this number contains all the digits from $0$ to $9$ at least one time).

In addition, I have to find out whether there exist other "constant numbers" (different from $U$).

Any hint or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have to do these things? Also, if $U$ is a constant number then clearly, any multiple of $U$ is one too.

Comment: No, sry I didn't write it clearly. I have to show that U is a "constant number". A "constant number" is a number which have the characteristic of each positive multiple from this number has got each number from 0 to 9 at least one time in it. So I have to proove that U is such a "constant number".

Comment: I googled the number and got two hits. They are in Chinese, but do seem to talk about this same phenomenon. Unfortunately, google translate just shows a blank page for these hits.

Comment: Yes, I even googled it. But the problem is that there is no answer of this problem.

Comment: No, you wrote it clearly enough. But I was asking for some context. Is it an assigned problem? Homework? It does seem quite hard, more like a puzzle. But at least, my remark answers the final part of your question.

Comment: Oh, now I realized that you're right. All multiples of U are also constant numbers. But the problem is that I haven't got an idea for prooving that U is an constant number. And this is not really a homework but my teacher gave me this problem and I try to solve it.

Comment: @groh I'm curious if there is some literature on such "constant numbers"

Comment: @Dal maybe your right. But I didn't find such a literature.

Answer (score 4):

It's not true.

$5263157894736842101 * 19 = 99999999999999999919$

Addendum:

Note if $n$ is relatively prime to $10$, then [Euler's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) says $10^{\varphi(n)} - 1$ is a multiple of $n$.

But $10^{\varphi(n)} - 1$ is a string of $9$'s. So $n$ cannot be "constant".

Addendum II: See ZoeH's comment below for the $\gcd(n,10) \ne 1$ case.

Comment: Oh, your right. Thanks

Comment: Do you know whether there are numbers which are really constant numbers?

Comment: I suspect that addendum might be extendible to show the answer is no.

Comment: @Neil I agree. Suppose $n$ is a constant number. There exists a positive integer $k$ such that $kn$ is of the form $10^ab$ where $\gcd(b,10) = 1$ ($k$ can be chosen to be a power of $2$ or $5$). Then every multiple of $b$ must contain all of the digits from $1$ to $9$ at least once, but some multiple of $b$ is a string of nines.

Comment: @ZoeH good, thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and consider the decimal expansion of $\dfrac{1}{n}$. Because $\dfrac{1}{n}$ is rational, its decimal expansion eventually terminates or repeats. Either way, the decimal expansion is of the form $$\dfrac{1}{n}=0.\mbox{[$d$ initial digits][repeating pattern $P$ of $k$ digits][$P$][$P$]}\dots,$$

where $P$ may be the one-digit pattern $0$. Then

$$\dfrac{10^{d}}{n}=\mbox{[$d$ initial digits].[$P$][$P$]}\dots=D+\dfrac{P}{99\cdots9}=\dfrac{99\cdots9\cdot D+P}{99\cdots9},$$

where $99\cdots9=10^k-1$, the integer represented by $k$ consecutive $9$s, and $D$ is the integer represented by the $d$ initial digits of the decimal representation of $\dfrac{1}{n}$.

Cross-multiplying gives

$$(99\cdots9\cdot D+P)n=99\cdots9\cdot10^d,$$

a multiple of $n$ whose decimal representation contains only the two digits $9$ and $0$.

This proves that $n$ is not a “constant number.”